# Why do control moment gyroscopes exhibit "torque amplification"?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque

There are a number of articles that describe the benefits of using control moment gyroscopes (CMGs) over reaction wheels in inertial navigation applications. One of the primary benefits of using a CMG [cited](http://www.google.com/search?q=cmg%20torque%20amplification) is a "torque amplification" effect, wherein you get greater effective output torque than the input torque at the gimbal. However, I couldn't find a good reference that explains or quantifies this phenomena. How does this occur?